# Center a JCheckBox in the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I need to add a Label in the NORTH and 3 CheckBoxes in the CENTER and 3 Buttons at the SOUTH.

So I've created 2 JPanels (Principal, and Inside_P)

```
private JPanel Principal, Inside_P;
private JLabel Title;
private JCheckBox in, dou, flo;
private JButton End;

Title= new JLabel("Conversion", JLabel.CENTER);     // Works (Center the Label in the middle of North)
in = new JCheckBox("Integer", JCheckBox.CENTER);     // Can't work (I don't know)
dou = new JCheckBox("Double");
flo = new JCheckBox("Float");


Principal= new JPanel();
Inside_P = new JPanel();

Principal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
Inside_P.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

Principal.add(Titre, BorderLayout.NORTH);
Principal.add(Inside, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Inside_P.add(in, BorderLayout.WEST);
Inside_P.add(dou, BorderLayout.CENTER);
Inside_P.add(flo, BorderLayout.EAST);

    Principal.add(End, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

What I need her is how can I center the 3 CheckBox in the Middle of the CENTER of the Pricipal JPanel ?

Comment: Please learn proper Java naming conventions for your variables. Every text book or tutorial I've ever read uses them, so don't make up your own. Also, what do you mean by center? Are you trying to center the components vertically or horizontally? Be specific. Finally, post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem so we can understand the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them grouped together, let the Inside_P JPanel keeps it's default FlowLayout manager.  If you add them, they will align in the center.  They will be centered, however they are at the top of the Inside_P JPanel.

Before you add your JCheckboxe's to the Inside_P container,

Try adding a Box spacer:

```
Inside_P.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
Inside_P.add( Box.createVerticalStrut( 160 ) );
Inside_P.add(in);
Inside_P.add(dou);
Inside_P.add(flo);
```

If the user decides to resize the window, the check boxes will not stay in the center vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Do the same thing - make your Principal JPanel use the BorderLayout, and place the third checkbox in the center.